# CodeIgniter error 404 page not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, web

I'm having trouble accessing pages or controller to be exact in codeigniter. The default controller working fine, but when I create a new controller it can not be accessed, when I exceute the url `http://localhost/codeigniter/admin/login` it shows error 404 Page Not Found. 
Here's my controller code, located in Codeigniter/applications/controllers/admin/Login.php

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Login Administrator',
            'isi' => 'admin/login_view'
        );

        $this
            ->load
            ->view('admin/login_view', $data)
        ;
    }
}
```

and here's my config code :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

and here's my .htaccess file, located in the root folder (CodeIgniter)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm using local server XAMPP, I did enable the rewrite module, changed the httpd.conf AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All, but still won't working. I'm stuck at this point so please help :) Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess is not working. If you try to hit this url

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/admin/login
```

its working,
for more details about how to remove "index.php" from codeigniter url you can refer this 
http://theprofessionguru.com/question/remove-indexphp-from-url-in-codeingiter

Comment: yes this url http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/admin/login is working. I did following the steps but still not working, even worse the main page did not showing

Comment: I don't know , but the steps are working for me, may be some problem in your xampp setup.

Comment: Yeah maybe, trying so hard solving it right now. But still, thankyou for your answer btw :)